# Redirect subfolder to another subfolder without appending parametres

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a subfolder to another subfolder, but I don't want to carry over what comes after the trailing slash or any URL parametres.

For example:

www.mysite.com/this-is-the-old/   ->  www.mysite.com/this-is-the-new/

But I would like this redirect to fire no matter what the user adds to the end of the old URL. No matter what I try (in either RedirectMatch or RewriteRule) it's always adding the trailing characters to the new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rewrite rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^this-is-the-old(/.*)?$ /this-is-the-new/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely before you test this new rule.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I was using similar syntax but not the ?$